# Open arrow with solid line in UML?

Tags: java, uml

In UML, what does an open arrow with a solid line show? Does it show Association (where the class with the tail knows about the class with the arrow head, while the arrow head class does not know about the tail class)?

Answer (score 47):

Not sure how you define "open arrow", but it's either represents an *extends* relation or an *association*.

[image]

Comment: Note that the last two arrow types are NOT part of UML class diagrams.  The first one is used in sequence diagrams (v1.4 and later) and the second one is inaccurate; asynchronous messages used an open half arrowhead prior to 1.4.  With 1.4 and later, the open arrowhead means asynchronous and the filled arrowhead means synchronous as in this list.  The half arrowhead filled has never been used.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically an association where a unidirectional relation exists between the two class. For e.g.

The OverdrawnAccountsReport class knows about the BankAccount class, but the BankAccount class does not know about the association

```
OverdrawnAccountsReport -> BankAccount
```

Like standard associations, the uni-directional association includes a role name and a multiplicity value, but unlike the standard bi-directional association, the uni-directional association only contains the role name and multiplicity value for the known class.

If you see close or triangle shape arrow between two class, then that represents parent - child relation.